# Add new class variable java + getter/setter method without editing class

Tags: java

Is there any way to create new class variable or method in java without editing class java

Example:

I have class Person

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

and in main class I process like this:

```
    Person personData = new Person();
    personData.setName("My Name");
    personData.setAddress("Address");

    List<Person> person = new ArrayList<Person>();
    person.add(personData);
```

I want to add new person variable in List
and have `setNo();` and `getNo();`

So list index[0] have person with property No, Name, And Address without editing the class Person first.

Comment: You cannot get/set a property(`No`) that is not there.

Comment: Java is strongly typed, that goes against this idea.

Comment: What would this "No" property be?  You don't give an example of why you think you need such a property.  Perhaps there is another way to accomplish what you want without it.

Comment: i have pagination integration in js library and java, in js.. it only accept response json list, even if i have many attribute in my json response, .. i dunno why in that pagination they not have No list, only start, end, currentPage, and ItemList(List From my java response), that why i dont want to edit js , pagination java, and i dont want that object inside list to have No class variable

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in Java to add methods to a class without changing the class source code.

The only possibility you have is to either extend from this class (by creating a subclass that inherits from Person) or to create a completely new class that contains a Person object.

The first concept is called *inheritance*; the second one *composition*. You can find a discussion of "one versus the other" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) for example.

But in essence the answer: step back and read a good book about Java.

Comment: The former known as "inheritance", the latter known as "composition", see [Composition vs Inheritance](https://www.google.com/search?q=Composition+vs+Inheritance).

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for idea, added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create another class which extends Person.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PersonNo extends Person {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonNo personData = new PersonNo();
        personData.setName("My Name");
        personData.setAddress("Address");

        List<PersonNo> person = new ArrayList<>();
        person.add(personData);
    }

    public void setNo(int n) {
        this.no = n;
    }

    public int getNo() {
        return this.no;
    }

    private int no;
}
```

This requires you to change the List type to "PersonNo" and to add "PersonNo"s, but it will give you the functionality you need.  If you create the List with "Person", you can add "PersonNo"s but you will not have the setNo/getNo unless you cast the "Person" into a (PersonNo).